# sort_order does not change from toogle sort button in Django Crispy forms

Tags: html, jquery, django, jinja2, django-crispy-forms

I am using django crispy forms and I have a toogle sort button to sort by `asc` or `desc` order.

I have a `SearchForm` like this:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    """Text-searching form."""

    ...
    sort_order = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    ....

    def __init__(self, user, language=None, show_builder=True, **kwargs):
        """Generate choices for other components in the same project."""
        self.user = user
        self.language = language
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.disable_csrf = True
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                ....
                Div(
                    Field("sort_by", template="snippets/sort-field.html"),
                    Field("sort_order", template="snippets/sort-order.html"),
                    css_class="btn-group search-group sort-field",
                    role="group",
                ),
                css_class="btn-toolbar",
                role="toolbar",
            ),
            ....
        )
```

I have the `sort-header.html` like this:

```
<div class="btn-group sort-order" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default search-field query-sort-toggle">
        <span title="Ascending" class="search-icon active asc">{% icon "sort-ascending.svg" %}</span>
        <span title="Descending" class="search-icon desc">{% icon "sort-descending.svg" %}</span>
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" id="id_sort_order" name="sort_order" value="{{ sort_order|default:'asc' }}" aria-label="{% trans "Sort Order" %}" />
</div>
```

and `jquery` for handling click event on `sort order` button:

```
$(".query-sort-toggle").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $label = $this.find("span.search-icon");
    $label.toggle();

    var sort_order = $label.attr('class').replace('search-icon active', '')
    var $toggleInput = $this.closest(".sort-order").find("input[name=sort_order]");
    $toggleInput.val(sort_order)

    ....
    if ($this.closest(".result-page-form").length) {
      $this.closest("form").submit();
    }
  });
```

When the button is clicked, the inactive span gets hidden by this css:

```
.query-sort-toggle span:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}
```

I have this toggle button and form gets submitted on the click.

The default sort order is `asc` order but when page reloads after the form submittion, the button still shows the default value.

I am able to sort by `asc` and `desc` order but I am not able to change the icon of the `span` and the `sort_order` variable.

What I am missing here?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. Is the right value submitted by your form and you just like to change the initail displayed search-icon based on the submitted sort_order?

Comment: The right value is not submitted by the form, that one blocker. and then yes, change the initail displayed search-icon based on the submitted sort_order.

Answer (score 1):

You could add some debug code to your JavaScript and look at the browser console to see if the right value is set to your form.

```js
$(".query-sort-toggle").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $label = $this.find("span.search-icon");
    $label.toggle();

    var sort_order = $label.attr('class').replace('search-icon active', '')
    var $toggleInput = $this.closest(".sort-order").find("input[name=sort_order]");
    $toggleInput.val(sort_order)
    // DEBUG
    console.debug('set sort_order value');
    console.debug(sort_order);

    ....
    if ($this.closest(".result-page-form").length) {
      $this.closest("form").submit();
    }
  });
```

You could even use your view to verify the submitted data

```py
def your_view(request):
    print(request.POST.get('sort_order')
    # ... your code
    context['sort_order] = sort_order
    return render(request, 'template/name.html', context)
```

If you made sure the right value is submitted, you can adjust the template to show the selected sort order icon

```html
<div class="btn-group sort-order" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default search-field query-sort-toggle">
        <span title="Ascending" class="search-icon {% if sort_order == 'asc' %}active{% endif %} asc">{% icon "sort-ascending.svg" %}</span>
        <span title="Descending" class="search-icon {% if sort_order == 'desc' %}active{% endif %} desc">{% icon "sort-descending.svg" %}</span>
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" id="id_sort_order" name="sort_order" value="{{ sort_order|default:'asc' }}" aria-label="{% trans "Sort Order" %}" />
</div>
```